# How to add metric "Unique screen views / session" in google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am new to google analytics, in the behavior tab I see that we can add "screen views/session" metric to the screens report. However, there's no metric for "unique screen views/session".

How can I add or implement such metric? I think sessions are automatically tracked by GA. The unique screen views are also tracked as a count metric but without the option to get the value per session.

Also how can I get the average unique screen views?

Comment: I found that I can add 'Sessions' (indicating number of sessions), is there anyway by which I can add a column to the table with the division of 'unique screen views' / 'sessions' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use [Calculated Metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en) to add "Unique screen views / session" metric. You can define a calculated metric and calculate its value from other predefined or custom metrics.

In my case I created a calculated metric with name "Unique Screen Views / Session" and formula:

```
{{Unique Screen Views}} / {{Sessions}}
```

where these values are the values of predefined metrics for session number and unique screen views count.